# Cómo pegar un valor en una tabla web que tiene un campo con menú desplegable?

Tags: html-tabla, http-get

Solicito su ayuda para encontrar la forma de pegar un valor en una tabla web que tiene un campo con menú desplegable.

Sólo he podido llegar a hacer click en dicho campo, pero usando Value, InnerText o InnerHTML, no he tenido éxito

El código que usé para ingresar un valor a la tabla web, es:

```
Sub InputWEBTable()
Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With IE
        .Navigate "http://variables/"
        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readystate = 4 'verifico si cargo correctamente la página
        .Visible = True
        .TheaterMode = True
    End With

    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("editor_edit")(1).Click

    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    IE.Document.getElementById("btnAgregarCapacitacion").Click

    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    Debug.Print IE.Document.getElementById("tblCapacitaciones").getElementsByClassName("odd")(0).getElementsByTagName("td").Length
    IE.Document.getElementById("tblCapacitaciones").getElementsByClassName("odd")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).Click
    IE.Document.getElementById("tblCapacitaciones").getElementsByClassName("odd")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText = "Curso"
End Sub
```

El código HTML asociado a la celda en la que hice click es:

```
<select class="form-control" id="DTE_Field_IdTipoCapacitacion">
<option disabled="" value="" hidden="">Seleccione...</option>
<option value="1">Inducción</option>
<option value="2">Charla de cinco minutos</option>
<option value="3">Charla de divulgación</option>
<option value="4">Curso</option>
<option value="5">Taller</option>
<option value="6">Jornada</option>
<option value="7">Capacitación en el puesto de trabajo</option>
<option value="8">Simulacros</option>
<option value="9">Otros</option>
</select>
```

Agradeceré vuestro apoyo para encontrar una forma de ingresar cualquiera de las opciones y dejar grabado ese valor en la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

No quisiera dejar abierta esta pregunta y publico la manera de cómo hallé una solución a mi problema.
La última línea de mi código la reemplazé por la siguiente:

ie.Document.getElementById("DTE_Field_IdTipoCapacitacion").Value = Capac(3, i)

Con ello aprendí que hay que identificar correctamente el objeto al que le debo asignar un valor.

Espero que sea útil a alguien que tenga un problema parecido.